# Formula to map 360 angle to 255 but coords x->y are flipped

Tags: java, algorithm, math, rotation, algebra

I suck at math and feel like this should be easy but I want it to be elegant instead of a hack.

I have a 360 degree angle that needs to be calculated on to a 255 degree freedom of rotation.
Person enters angle, outputs accurately to a 255 degree circle.

```
int north = 90;
float outputNorth = north/360f * 255f; //Results: 90 angle-> 63 angle
```

But it needs to be:

```
int north = 90;
float outputNorth = north/xf* yf; //Results: 90 angle -> 128 angle
```

Problem: 
Coords are a little weird for the 255 degree of rotation. Not sure how to translate it.

```
Should be the following:
//90 -> 128

//0 -> 192

//270 -> 0

//180 -> 64
```

[image: SEE THIS PICTURE!!! -> 360 coords mapped to 255 cords, but it needs to be the resulting cords]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math has some rounding problems. I would use a different mapping where 360 deg would be `256 -> 0` instead of `255`. Otherwise your 8bit values would have the same angle `0` stored twice and it would most likely cause other problems latter.

Here conversion to/from deg/8bit using **linear interpolation**:

```
int i;     // angle [deg int]
int o;     // 0..255 [8bit uint]

o=(192-((i<<8)/360))&255;

i=((192-o)*360)>>8;
```

Here the values:

```
  i   o
  0 192
 90 128
180  64
270   0
360 192
```

The `i` can be any even negative or bigger than 360 deg the conversion will still work...